# iOS Autolayout constraint between non-siblings

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, uivisualeffectview

Is there a way to define a horizontal distance constraint between two views which are not siblings? I tried to add a constraint to their first common superview but the constraint doesn't seem to work.

The Apple documentation says:

> *The constraint may only reference the view itself or its subviews.*

But I'm not sure if they meant **direct** subviews or not.

**Rationale:**
I have a view where I want to put different children and arrange them. Some of those children should be shown with vibrancy effect. Unfortunately, enabling or disabling the vibrancy of a view in iOS is done through placing it in a `UIVisualEffectView`. So in order to have a mixture of vibrant and non-vibrant views I am using two containers in my top level view - one for vibrant views and the other for the rest. However, I need to arrange the visual items relative to each other with constraints. But since they are in different containers, I need the constraints to work for non-sibling views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to support the ~3% of users still on iOS 7, just don't manually add constraints to *any* view:

> When developing for iOS 8.0 or later, set the constraint’s active
>   property to true instead. This automatically adds the constraint to
>   the correct view.

Create a constraint referring to both views, make sure they're in the same view hierarchy, activate it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that! One extra question on that - should I somehow retain that constraint or not? I create it programmatically in a function, have it in a local variable and after setting the 'active' to YES I exit the function. As I understood - it will call `addConstraint` which should retain, so I don't need to hold it, right?

Comment: No need to retain. Underneath what it does is find the correct view to add the constraint to and add it there. So somebody else assumes ownership. I guess Apple realised that finding a common parent automatically is boilerplate code they should just provide; doing it manually and not sometimes getting it wrong for non-trivial hierarchies is unlikely. (editorial: though it is a bit odd versus expectations that `[NSLayoutConstraint layoutConstraintWithItem:...].active = YES;` then creates an onward-living item, so I tend to use the `[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:]` form regardless)

Answer (score 1):

You can make this constraint it by dragging constraint line with Control button pressed. Here is an example.
1) Two views in different containers, red and blue, where red has X position constraint, but blue one doesn't have it:
[image]
[image]
2) Pressing `Control` button, drag line from blue to red, and you will see constraint menu, where you should select `Horizontal Spacing` for this case:
[image]
3) Choose `Horizontal Spacing` from this menu, and you're done:
[image]